# How to add multi select dropdown and comma seprated field from phtml in admin panel

Tags: magento-1.9, multiselect-attribute, drop-downs

I  am new to magento, I have to add multi select drop down and a comma separated field to magento admin panel using phtml file, can any one guide me for this. thanks...

Comment: Sorry, slipped from mind

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can add comma separated in option it like below

```
<?php    $values='a,b,c,d,e';
    $array=explode(',',$values);
    ?>

 <select multiple name="option[]"> <?php foreach($array as $value)
{  ?>
  <option value="<?php echo $value ?>"><?php echo $value ?></option>
<?php } ?> 

</select>
```