# Magento query is not working

Tags: magento-1.9, collection, sql, query

I have craated following magento query,

```
$orderCollection->getSelect()->joinLeft(array('sfoa' => 'sales_flat_order_address'), 'main_table.entity_id = sfoa.parent_id', "");
            $orderCollection->addFieldToFilter('sfoa.address_type', array('eq' => 'shipping'));
            $orderCollection->getSelect()->joinLeft(array('caev' => 'customer_address_entity_varchar'), 'caev.entity_id = sfoa.customer_address_id', "");
            $orderCollection->addFieldToFilter('caev.attribute_id', array('eq' => 143));
            $orderCollection->addFieldToFilter('caev.value', array('nin' => $excludeStoresIds));
```

and its sql equivalent statement is

```
SELECT `main_table`.* FROM `sales_flat_order` AS `main_table
 LEFT JOIN `sales_flat_order_address` AS `sfoa` ON main_table.entity_id = sfoa.parent_id
 LEFT JOIN `customer_address_entity_varchar` AS `caev` ON caev.entity_id = sfoa.customer_address_id WHERE (created_at >= '16-02-8' AND created_at <= '2016-02-11') AND 
(sfoa.address_type = 'shipping') AND (caev.attribute_id = 143) AND (caev.value NOT IN('2323'))
```

if I directly run above sql statement,it gives correct result, but magento query is not running **AND (caev.value NOT IN('2323'))** part of query

Comment: @Qaisar is there any problem in query

Comment: is this array $excludeStoresIds?

Comment: Yes, $excludeStoresIds is an array

Comment: generated sql query gives exact result, but magento query is not executing '$orderCollection->addFieldToFilter('caev.value', array('nin' => $excludeStoresIds));'

Comment: check it `$collection->getAllIds()` return the correct result?

Comment: Yes, **$id[] = $orderCollection->getAllIds();**, $id[] has correct result,(4 results), but if I do **count($orderCollection)**, it shows 7,

Comment: i faced the same problem so i did `$orderCollection->addFieldToFilter('entity_id', array('in' => $orderCollection->getAllIds()));` its give me correct result

Comment: Thanks, working fine, than you so much, can you post its answer,

Comment: can accept this too if it is helpful http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/92804/how-to-add-multi-select-dropdown-and-comma-seprated-field-from-phtml-in-admin-pa

Comment: anyone could ans my question please? http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/101137/how-to-show-payu-iframe-on-checkout-page-after-order-review-question-with-all-d

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to get `getAllIds` filter  from collection. and again put filter on collection.

`$orderCollection->addFieldToFilter('entity_id', array('in' => $orderCollection->getAllIds()));`

Answer (score 0):

$excludeStoresIds - convert to a string and try...
e.g. array('nin' => array(15,25,35,40,41,42,43)));
$excludeStoresIds = implode(',', $excludeStoresIds);